# org.apache.jasper.JasperException lost in logback, but written to tomcat9 localhost.log

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logback, java-10, tomcat9

My goal is to have all app-level logging go to my app log file.  My problem is that while a lot of my debug/info/error messages make it to STDOUT/File etc... here is one error that only shows in my tomcat9 log:

```
 4-Jun-2018 08:55:29.050 SEVERE [http-nio-82-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/di_queue.jsp (line: [110], column: [8]) The function [isCurrentUser] cannot be located with the specified prefix
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor$1FVVisitor.visit(Validator.java:1603)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ELNode$Function.accept(ELNode.java:135)
```

I am using jdk 10, Spring 5.0.5, Hibernate 5.3, Logback 1.2.3

Here is my logback.xml

```
    <configuration scan="true">

      <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
          <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
      </appender>

    <logger name="org.directwebremoting" level="trace"
            additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.apache.tiles" level="info"
            additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        </logger>

<logger name="org.apache.jasper.compiler" level="info"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

      <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      </root>

    </configuration>
```

Here is my ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.apache" module="ews" />
    <configurations defaultconfmapping="default">
        <conf name="default" />
        <conf name="compile" description="compile dependencies" extends="default" />
        <conf name="runtime" description="runtime dependencies" extends="default" />
        <conf name="test" description="test dependencies" extends="default" />
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="5.3.0.Final">
        </dependency>

        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-jcache"
            rev="5.3.0.Final" />

        <!-- just for ehcahce 2? -->
        <!-- <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-ehcache" rev="5.3.0.Final" 
            /> -->


        <!-- needed or whole hibernate spring config does not start -->
        <dependency org="org.springframework.boot" name="spring-boot-starter-cache"
            rev="2.0.2.RELEASE" />

        <dependency org="javax.cache" name="cache-api" rev="1.1.0" />
        <dependency org="org.ehcache" name="ehcache" rev="3.5.2" />

        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-orm"
            rev="5.0.6.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core"
            rev="5.0.6.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-access" rev="1.2.3" />

        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc"
            rev="5.0.6.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-web"
            rev="5.0.6.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context"
            rev="5.0.6.RELEASE" />

        <dependency org="org.springframework.boot" name="spring-boot-starter-logging"
            rev="2.0.2.RELEASE" />


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.directwebremoting/dwr rev="2.0.1" 
            rev="3.0.2-RELEASE" -->
        <dependency org="org.directwebremoting" name="dwr"
            rev="3.0.2-RELEASE" />





        <dependency org="dom4j" name="dom4j" rev="1.6.1" />


        <dependency org="net.sf.jasperreports" name="jasperreports"
            rev="3.6.1" /><!-- 6.6.0 -->

        <dependency org="jstl" name="jstl" rev="1.2" />

        <dependency org="javax.servlet" name="servlet-api" rev="2.5" />

        <dependency org="net.sf.supercsv" name="super-csv-dozer"
            rev="2.4.0" />

        <!-- <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="jcl-over-slf4j" rev="1.7.22" /> 
            <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j" name="log4j-slf4j-impl" rev="2.7" 
            /> <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j" name="log4j-api" rev="2.7" 
            /> <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j" name="log4j-core" rev="2.7" 
            /> -->


        <!-- for the ant classes remove after ant jrc working -->
        <!-- <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.2" 
            /> <dependency org="org.codehaus.groovy" name="groovy-all" rev="1.5.5" /> 
            <dependency org="org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler" name="ecj" rev="4.6.1" /> -->



        <dependency org="org.apache.tiles" name="tiles-jsp" rev="3.0.8" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.tiles" name="tiles-core" rev="3.0.8" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.tiles" name="tiles-api" rev="3.0.8" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.tiles" name="tiles-servlet"
            rev="3.0.8" />


        <dependency org="commons-fileupload" name="commons-fileupload"
            rev="1.3.3" />


        <dependency org="javax.mail" name="javax.mail-api" rev="1.6.1" />

        <dependency org="com.mchange" name="c3p0" rev="0.9.5.2" />



        <dependency org="org.json" name="json" rev="20180130" />
        <dependency org="javax.json" name="javax.json-api" rev="1.1.2" />

        <dependency org="commons-validator" name="commons-validator"
            rev="1.6" />


        <dependency org="org.mozilla" name="rhino" rev="1.7R1" />


        <!-- <dependency org="org.acegisecurity" name="acegi-security" rev="1.0.4" 
            /> -->
        <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="spring-security-web"
            rev="5.0.5.RELEASE" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework.security" name="spring-security-config"
            rev="5.0.5.RELEASE" />

        <dependency org="com.lowagie" name="itext" rev="2.1.7" />



        <dependency org="org.apache.tomcat" name="tomcat-catalina"
            rev="9.0.8" />



        <dependency org="com.microsoft.sqlserver" name="mssql-jdbc"
            rev="6.4.0.jre9" />
        <!-- https://www.concretepage.com/forum/thread?qid=531 -->
        <dependency org="javax.xml.bind" name="jaxb-api" rev="2.3.0" />

        <dependency org="oro" name="oro" rev="2.0.8" />

        <dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3"
            rev="3.7" />

        <dependency org="commons-fileupload" name="commons-fileupload"
            rev="1.3.3" />


    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Seems like JSP/view/tiles/dwr errors are the ones I am missing in STDOUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Servlet related exception logs are handled by Tomcat internal logging library which is a customised java.util.logging.

According to [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html#Servlets_logging_API) :

> The calls to javax.servlet.ServletContext.log(...) to write log
>   messages are handled by internal Tomcat logging. Such messages are
>   logged to the category named
>
> `org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[${engine}].[${host}].[${context}]`

To overwrite the global Tomcat logging configuration , try to put a java.util.logging 's properties file `logging.properties` in `/WEB-INF/classes/` and configure the above logger log to a file handler , somethings like this:

```
handlers =java.util.logging.FileHandler

java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern   =  /temp/app.log


org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
```